# Bootstrap table single cell hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

while creating a calendar I have stumbled upon the question on how to make the cells have a bootstrap 4 hover effect.

[How the calendar looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh8WX.png)

I want the cells to have a hover effect similar to [Hoverable rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#hoverable-rows) without changing the Bootstraps CSS.

Any tips? And while I'm at it: Is there any way to make the table be completely symmetrical (square cells)

EDIT:

`table td:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}`

is [not realy working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drOMg.png). The cell should be a darker blue, not gray.

Comment: square cells: use padding; for hover effect: you don't want to write your own CSS class for hover ?

Comment: do you wanna hover for single cell, look out my answer or change my confusion !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that

```css
table td:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you but this sadly doesn't work if one or more fields are colored..

Comment: what is the means of that _one or more fields are colored._

Comment: change background color to your favourite color like dark blue !! simple